# Deploying Flutter web with in Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, deployment

I want to deploy a flutter web project within the Laravel project. I tried using flutter build and adding all project files within resources\views\index.Html and all build files given out of flutter build. I am not trying to use Firebase for hosting.

how to deploy flutter web build with Laravel build project in combine like Vue + Laravel for server hosting?

Comment: Somehow a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335354/how-to-solve-index-conflict-inside-public-folder-of-laravel-app

Answer (score 0):

We cant merge flutter development into Laravel yet as flutter web is not completely in stable version and with that, it might not be implemented too, the alternative to it is performing hosting and sub hosting in servers for now. A better solution as flutter web development is very powerful and provides PWA services automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your build files (js, css) also in **public** folder, and make app.js in public and put add.js in resource also just for require bootstrap (different app.js file).

Also in vue + laravel should do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).